# About similar export lines in ~/.bash_profile

Tags: macos, bash

Is it correct to have two lines of export in ~/.bash_profile? the lines are very similar. Im in macosx Mavericks.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: That's not two lines.

Comment: If it actually is two lines, then only the second one has any effect.

Answer (score 0):

On different lines, yes or separated by `;`:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Although legal, there is no need for the duplication.

Comment: Great I will going to delete the first one.